# find result in IN CLAUSE not in other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables t1 and t2.
I have particular 100 records which are present in t1 table. I want to find, out of 100 records which records are not present in t2 table.
I tried using left join, but its giving me result which are present t2 table

PS - t1 table has more than 100 records, i have particular records which i wanna search.
Also t1.ID= t2.ID

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: Hint: You could actually use a sql clause found right in the title of your question (`not in`). Alternatively (*and actually preferred over not in*) try `not exists`.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @Jens select a.id from t1 a
Left out join t2 b on
(A.id=b.id)
Where b.id is NULL
And b.id in (--100 records)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your where is wrong it must be `a.id in` not `b.id in`:

```
select a.id from t1 a Left out join t2 b on (A.id=b.id) Where b.id is NULL and a.id in (--100 records)
```

Because `b.id` can not be `null` and a value of your list